resileince4j circuit breaker does not catch exception registered as recorded
In my sample spring cloud application I have a gateway server with the following configs:
@Bean
    RouteLocator routesConfig(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
   //Part of code is omitted for conciseness

        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/isoft-bank/accounts/**")
                        .filters(f ->
                                f.rewritePath("/isoft-bank/accounts/(?<rest>.*)", restPattern)
                                        .addResponseHeader(xResponseTime, currDate)
                                        .circuitBreaker(config -> config
                                                .setName("accountsCB")
                                                .setFallbackUri(callSupport)))
                        .uri("lb://ACCOUNTS"))
                .build();
    }

and configs in config server:
//Part of config-server.yml omitted for conciseness

resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    configs:
      default:
        sliding-window-size: 5 
        sliding-window-type: time_based
        permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state: 2
        failure-rate-threshold: 50 
        wait-duration-in-open-state: 10000 
        record-exceptions:
          - java.lang.Throwable
      accountsCB:
        sliding-window-size: 10
        sliding-window-type: count_based
        permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state: 3
        failure-rate-threshold: 45
        wait-duration-in-open-state: 8000
        record-exceptions:
          - java.lang.Throwable

and fall back class:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class FallBackController {

    @RequestMapping("/callSupport")
    public Mono<String> callSupport() {
        return Mono.just("something went wrong,if  the problem persists call (+098) 123 456 789");
    }
}

as its clear from the above properties, all types of exceptions are considered as recorded exception so that when the circuit breaker sees such kind of exception it treat it is as a failure and call the fallback uri.this is what I expect but when I call the URL :http://localhost:8100/isoft-bank/accounts/api/v1/get-customer-details?mobileNumber=09123123213 which goes to the gateway server then to the accounts service and the following method in the service layer will get executed:
public CustomerDetailsDTO getCustomerDetails(@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{11}$", message = "please provide a valid mobile number") String mobileNumber,
                                                 @RequestHeader String correlationId) {

        CustomerDTO customerDTO = customerService.findByMobileNumber(mobileNumber);
        AccountDTO accountDTO = accountService.findByCustomerId(customerDTO.getId());
        CardsDto cardsDto = cardsClient.getCardsDetail(mobileNumber, correlationId).getBody();
        LoansDto loansDto = loansClient.getLoanDetails(mobileNumber, correlationId).getBody();

        //custom exception throwing for testing purpose
        if (true) throw new RuntimeException("ALIII");

        return CustomerMapper.CustomerDetailsMapper.get().toDTO(customerDTO, accountDTO, cardsDto, loansDto);
    }

I tried this and all the codes before the throwing exception are working and the exception will be thrown successfully and I also provided this global exception handler logic to be sure the exception is not caught anywhere in program:
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> globalExceptionsHandler(Exception e, WebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {
        if (true)
            throw e;
        else
            return this.getResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), webRequest, e);
    }

but the returned response is:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-11-05T11:53:55.117+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/v1/get-customer-details"
}

and not the message is provided in fallback uri which is: "something went wrong, if the problem persists call (+098) 123 456 789".
also when I call the http://localhost:8100/actuator/circuitbreakerevents this request is considered as success:
[
  {
            "circuitBreakerName": "accountsCB",
            "type": "SUCCESS",
            "creationTime": "2024-11-05T16:03:17.720247700+03:30[Asia/Tehran]",
            "errorMessage": null,
            "durationInMs": 31,
            "stateTransition": null
        }
]

I would appreciate it if you could help me.
